DXL - Flagging deleted object text
I currently have a dxl that will delete too much text when running to delete indentations from the object text. Since I have been working on fixing this issue, it seems it isn't straightforward at all so I am trying to flag the objects where the text has been deleted too much. I have been having issues with this as my code I come with flags every single object instead of the ones with deleted text. How would I fix this?
Assigning a string the original obj."Object Text" before attempting to delete the indentations and then assigned another string the object text after the deletions occur and then comparing them.

"I have issues with my code" / "How can I fix this" is not a very detailed question. What exactly do you want to ask for? How to flag an object? How to compare RichText of strings? How to copy values from one variable to another?

I thought it seems very straightforward what I was asking above, but I can reword it if you would like. I need to flag the object text (so an object attribute) before and after the delete indentations is ran and then I need the object text to be compared from the original to the object text after the function has been ran and if the object text is different it needs to be flagged (not including the rich text that clearly was already deleted). I tried assigning these two different object text to a string a this did not fix the issue (even when I compared the RichText of strings)

I don't know how to make this any more detailed then this comment but my solution flagged every single object that had object text so

without any code excerpts it is hard to guess what your exact problem is.  You can "flag" an object by using commands like for o in entire m do {if (<some condition>) then o."MyFlag" = "xxx"} but I guess you already know this. Which code do you use e.g. for your condition?
